# Batch file - search for a list of words in a file and print out lines not containing them

Tags: batch-file, text, cmd

So I am trying to write a batch file for the following purpose,
File 1 contains lot of text content, with the keyword 'code' serving as a variable, i.e. code always has a value assigned to it like code=0145. File 2 contains a list of values for code. 
The batch file when run would look through file 1 for the values mentioned in file 2 and omit the lines if it finds them.
e.g.

```
File 1:
This line has code=0145
We have code=3257
Code=8956 here
This entry has code=7542

File 2:
3257
7542

Output file 3:
This line has code=0145
Code=8956 here
```

Is this possible via batch file?

Comment: You might be able to use grep -v option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FINDSTR /i /L "code=" "1.txt"|FINDSTR /v /g:"2.txt">3.txt
```

may be suitable. It first looks for the text "code=" (`/i` means case-insensitive) and for the lines containing that text, selects those that `/v` DON'T contain any of the text in the "2.txt" file.

Now, having said that, the line

```
Bad data 3257 code=7777
```

is skipped as `3257` is contained in the text and

```
Bad data code=17542
```

is skipped as `7542` is contained in the text, albeit in the `code` string.

For that matter, if `123` is in the `2.txt` file, then any line containing `123` will be excluded, including `code=1234` and `code=7123`.

It *is* possible to detect `code=string` appearing in the text, and also code=string<kbd>Space</kbd> but the approach is slightly different. More information needed. Like - is the code *always* 4 digits, etc?

---

Given that the code number is 4 digits and implicitly the string `code=9999` is required, then

```
(FOR /f %%a IN (2.txt) DO ECHO code=%%a)>2.tmp
FINDSTR /i /L "code=" "1.txt"|FINDSTR /v /g:"2.tmp"
```

The first line takes each line of `2.txt`, and regurgitates them prefixed by `code=` into a file called `2.tmp`. The `for` loop is parenthesised in order that the output can be redirected to the new file `2.tmp`.

The second line first filters the source data for lines containing `code=` then with the result excludes lines containing any of the lines in `2.tmp`.

If you want lines that *don't* contain `code=` as well, then use

```
FINDSTR /v /g:"2.tmp" "1.txt"
```

Comment: Yes indeed. The pattern i.e. code=**** is the same always, meaning it's 4 digit. However it could appear at any point of the line as indicated in the example i posted.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will test it right away and let you know the results. However, just to learn, in case it was not limited to 4 digits, what would have the approach been?

Comment: If all codes are 4 digits, simply adding `code=` to each of the entries in `2.txt` is adequate, since `code=123` and `code=12345` will not exist in the file. If the codes are variable length, then `1234` in `2.txt` would also match `code=12345`. To get over that problem, you'd need to detect two situations; the code at the end of the line and the code within the line & implicitly followed by a space. This would need the tempfile to contain `code=1234$` for eol and `code=1234 ` for in-line. This would not detect `code=12345` in either position (assuming `findstr/r` - default & limited regex)